# Как заполнить массив объектами, считанными из файла?

Tags: java, массивы, файлы, объекты

Дан файл. В нём построчно записаны поля в соответствующем порядке. Нужно считать поля файла, создав объекты и затем записать эти объекты в массив. Почему-то при записи объектов считываю их правильно, но записывается только последний. Что делать.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file_directory, file_name;
        int changer = -1;
        System.out.println("Enter amount of objects you want to add");
        int n = Typetester.SetInt();
        ArrayList<Route> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        while (changer != 0) {
            System.out.println("1 - Add object to file");
            System.out.println("2 - Add objects to array");
            System.out.println("0 - Exit");
            changer = Typetester.SetInt();
            switch (changer) {
                case 1:
                    new_object_to_file(file1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    add_to_array(file1, n, arr);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    changer = 0;
                    System.out.println("Exiting program...");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void add_to_array(File file1, int n, ArrayList<Route> arr1) {
        int curr_number, curr_price;
        String curr_last_station, curr_time, buff;

        try (Scanner fl = new Scanner(file1)){
            int j = 0;
            while(j != n) {
                curr_number = fl.nextInt();
                buff = fl.nextLine();
                curr_last_station = fl.nextLine();
                curr_time = fl.nextLine();
                curr_price = fl.nextInt();
                buff = fl.nextLine();
                arr1.add(new Route(curr_number, curr_last_station, curr_time, curr_price));
                j++;
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            arr1.get(i).show();
        }
    }
    public static void show_array(ArrayList<Route> arr, int n){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            arr.get(i).show();
        }
    }

public class Route{
    public static int number;
    public static String last_station;
    public static String time_of_departure;
    public static int price;

    Route(int Number, String Last_station, String Time_of_departure,
          int Price){
        this.number = Number;
        this.last_station = Last_station;
        this.time_of_departure = Time_of_departure;
        this.price = Price;
    }



    public void add_to_file(File file1){
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file1, true)) {
            writer.write(number + "\r\n");
            writer.write(last_station + "\r\n");
            writer.write(time_of_departure + "\r\n");
            writer.write(price + "\r\n");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Number: " + this.number);
        System.out.println("Last Station: " + this.last_station);
        System.out.println("Time of Departure: " + this.time_of_departure);
        System.out.println("Price: " + this.price);
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void clear(){
        this.number = 0;
        this.last_station = null;
        this.time_of_departure = null;
        this.price = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сильно много букаф в коде :) Упростите свой пример, минимизируйте его, выбросьте всё, что к делу не относится -- тогда, может, и сами увидите причину.

Comment: киньте считывание из файла. остальной код режет глаза

Comment: Сократил по максимуму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите 'static' из определения полей класса Route. При вызове конструктора вы просто перезаписываете значения полей, которые общие для всего класса, соответственно выводиться будут последние значения, переданные в конструктор.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, вы очень помогли мне с лабораторной работой! Дай вам бог